How to draw stacked/partially overlapped blocks in Tikz to indicate many items?
I am trying to make something similar to this below (drawn using another software) but in Tikz

Currently I use tikz/forest to make my flow diagrams. But I do not know how to make such stacked/partially overlapped rectangles to indicate many modules.
Here is MWE I have
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, text width=5em , inner sep=2pt, text centered}   }  

\newcommand\set[1]{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.8in}\raggedright%
#1
\end{minipage}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={forked edge,edge+={->},grow=east}
%
[\set{dsolve}
   [\set{first order ode}
       [\set{first order linear in $y'$}]         
       [\set{first order none linear in $y'$}]
   ]
   [\set{second order ode}
       [\set{type 1}]
       [\set{type 2}]
       [\set{type 3}]
   ]  
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

Gives

How to makes stacked/partially covered rectangles as shown in the top image? I do not have to use forest to do this, but this is what I currently use to make flow diagrams.
I searched google but can't find one example to learn from. I found only one image that I am sure was done in tikz here

But the code is not shown in the above link so do not know how it was done.  The above is similar to what I am trying to do.

Out of curiosity: how do you represent a flow diagram by a tree? Sounds a bit strange to me, or at least limited to certain flows.

@MS-SPO I am open for alternative if there is a better way.  But I learned this from this post

Quick hack: use shadows
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={forked edge,edge+={->},grow=east,draw=black,text width=3cm, l sep=1cm, s sep=0.5cm, fork sep=0.5cm,fill=white}
%
[dsolve
   [first order ode
       [first order linear in $y'$]         
       [first order none linear in $y'$]
   ]
   [second order ode, double copy shadow
       [type 1]
       [type 2]
       [type 3]
   ]  
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}



Thanks. But this does it on each and every node in the flow diagram. I only wanted to do it some selected ones, not on everyone. Is there a way to make this shadowing effect show only on a specific node?

@Nasser You can choose to which nodes you add the shadow

Here are a few alternatives without forest. I didn't add "decorations", like using arrows.meta, other arrow-shapes etc. by intention, which would hide the relevant parts.

dsolve is a regular node, using the box-style (use align option etc. as needed)
\pic draws some nodes, filled white
as far as I see, forest can't include \pics
as you can see e.g. here, pics are no nodes , so you need to provide some internal coordinates to access
the red arrow just demonstrates that you have to deliberatly ignore the nodes shape mechanisms (arrow would end there), IF you want to overlay it
the first shadow uses a double copy with negative xshift, while the second just uses the defaults, inspired by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz answer


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw,fill=white,
                minimum width=1cm,minimum height=5mm},
    ovbx/.pic={\foreach \c in {0,.1,.2,.3}
                    \node[box] (X\c) at (\c,-\c) {};
                \coordinate (-WE) at (X0.west);% else name won't work
              }, 
 ]
    % ~~~ using said pic ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[box]  (A) at (0,0) {dsolve};
    \pic        (B) at (2,0) {ovbx};
    
    \draw[->] (A) -- (B-WE) node[xshift=17mm] {pic};
    
    % ~~~ just to demo the arrows overlay ~~~~
    \draw[red,->] (.4,-.15) -- +(1,-1);
    
    % ~~~ applying a shadow ~~~~~~~
    \node[box,double copy shadow={shadow xshift=-.5ex}] (C) 
                                at (2,1) {shadow};

    \node[box,double copy shadow] (D) at (4,2) {shadow};
    
    \draw[->] (A) |- (C)  ;
    \draw[->] (C) -| (D)  ;
    
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

